# Есть ли разница в строчных и заглавных буквах в headers http

Tags: http

Есть ли разница в строчных и заглавных буквах в headers http?

Например два заголовка:

```
test: 123
Test: 123
```

Они будут считаться одинаковыми или разными?

Comment: Где именно? Вы о чем?

Comment: network в девтулзах

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Зависит от того в каком языке и как их получать.

Для примера: язык PHP. Если эти данные брать из переменной `$_SERVER`, то там все эти заголовки будут в виде:

```
HTTP_НАИМЕНОВАНИЕ_ЗАГОЛОВКА
```

то есть с префиксом `HTTP_` и далее наименование заглавными буквами с нижним подчёркиванием, независимо от того как будет написано. Т.е.

```
test -> HTTP_TEST
Testy -> HTTP_TESTY
hello_world -> HTTP_HELLO_WORLD
hi-its-me -> HTTP_HI_ITS_ME
```

Однако если использовать [getallheaders()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getallheaders.php), то результатом будет ассоциативный массив с ключами ровно в том регистре и том наименовании, как были написаны:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Во фреймворке *Yii2* вообще у каждого слова первая буква приводится к верхнему регистру. И если передаём `hi-its-me`, то обращаться придётся `Yii::$app->request->headers->get('Hi-Its-Me')`. И получается конфуз как раз с именем одинаковым, но в разном регистре...одно перетрёт другое ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

А заголовки с нижним подчёркиванием фреймворк вообще проигнорит и их в коллекции не будет.

---

Так что ответ: **зависит...**

Но обычно всё совпадает с переданным...

---

Comment: Зависит, хотя по спеке этой зависимости не должно быть https://stackoverflow.com/a/41169947/9435985

Comment: @TotalPusher всё как в жизни: ожидание и реальность))